# cron scheduler with jobs dependency

Tags: dependencies, cron

Our project has some distributed daily jobs which run in "crontab" and there are some dependencies between them. And we want job schedule is independent with our project(it seems like using Quartz should change current code). Does there any open source software provides functions like web-based cron management and jobs dependency?

[MiniCron](https://github.com/jamesrwhite/minicron) meets our requirements except job dependency.

Comment: you can use quratz scheduler thus it provides clustering between multiple crons.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check our free and open-source project [QuartzDesk Executor](https://github.com/quartzdesk/quartzdesk-executor) (QE) on GitHub.

QE is a generic Java Quartz scheduler-based webapp that you can use to build a centralized and clusterable job scheduling solution. Out--of-the box it provides several useful Quartz job implementation classes that allow you to schedule arbitrary executable scripts/applications etc. So you can easily use QE as a Unix/Linux cron replacement.

While QE can be used as is, I think it is best to use it with our commercial product called [QuartzDesk](https://www.quartzdesk.com). QuartzDesk provides a powerful GUI through which you can connect to your local / remote Quartz scheduler instances, modify jobs and schedules (triggers) and define job chains etc. Job chains allow you to implement arbitrary job dependencies.

If you do not want to use QuartzDesk, you can use any JMX-based Quartz scheduler management GUI. I do not have any experience with these alternative GUIs, but I am aware of projects named MySchedule and Quartz Manager. You can search for them on Google/GitHub. I do not think these tools currently provide support for job chains / job dependencies, but you can possibly fork and extend these tools.